# Analysing self-inductance per unit length at different locations inside a solenoid

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-induction, inductance

I learnt that the self-inductance $L$ of a long solenoid is given by the following formula:

$$L=\mu_0n^2\pi r^2 l$$

where $n$ is the number of turns per unit length, $r$ is the radius and $l$ is the length. It can be seen that the self-inductance depends only on the geometric parameters. But I don't understand whether "geometric parameters" includes the position where we measure the inductance in the solenoid. Or in other words whether the value of self-inductance vary whether we measure it near the ends or at the centre of the solenoid.

For this purpose, I tried to analyse the self-inductance per unit length of the solenoid which is given by the following equation (after a small rearrangement of the formula above):

$$L/l=\mu_0n^2\pi r^2$$

On this lines, it seems self-inductance is independent of the position in the solenoid as all terms on the right hand site are constant for a given system. However, I face a contradiction when I approach this on the basis of the meaning of self-inductance. It's just a measure of how much the magnetic flux changes at a particular point in the loop when electric current in the same loop varies. From the field lines of a solenoid, I could see the magnetic field lines are denser in the middle and comparatively rarer at the ends. So as per this method, it seems the value of self-inductance depends on the location in the solenoid.

In short, my question is - does self-inductance per unit length of a solenoid at the centre differ from that near its ends?

Comment: @AbsoluteZero, below, is correct.  I'll also add that the formula you posted is derived for an ideal, infinite solenoid, where talking about "the ends" of the solenoid is meaningless anyway.

Answer (score 1):

> However, I face a contradiction when I approach this on the basis of the meaning of self-inductance. It's just a measure of how much the magnetic flux changes at a particular point in the loop when electric current in the same loop varies.

That is where you are wrong. Magnetic flux is defined for an area/loop and not for a point. Inductance of solenoid thus, is the net flux passing through all the loops of the solenoid for unit current passing through the solenoid. It is a property of the solenoid as a whole and is not measured for point.

Thus there is no doubt that whether inductance at middle is different from ends as it is not defined for ends or middle region.

P.S.- Perhaps you are confused by Magnetic Field and how it varies rather than flux.

Edit 1- Now, if you are considering middle section of solenoid and end section separately and defining inductance separately then you will also need to define mutual inductance for other loops in proximity and it leads to a ton of hotch-potch. I hope you get the point.